# Android Input type for EditText IFSC code

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I need to give the input type for IFSC code which accepts only digits and characters. If anybody know pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow only digits and characters:

```
 android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:inputType="number"` in XML for EditText.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Allow only letters or digits
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ifsc_et);
    text.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter,new InputFilter.LengthFilter(11)});
```